# Convolution of multiple gaussian filters with different sizes

Tags: image-processing, filtering

What is the size of the final filter after implement convolution of multiple gaussian filters with different sizes?

Comment: An easy way to find put the exact answer is to tale the Fourier transform which will turn the convolution into a multiplication. Furthermore you can find the expression for the Gaussian Fourier transform. Then perform the multiplication and backtransform.

Comment: Wasn't this answered here? https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/a/258/209